# It is possible to run a command in a running C# program from PHP?

Tags: c#, php

I have a C# console application program running on windows server anytime.
On the same machine I have zend server and apache running.

It is possible to send a command to the **running** C# program directly from the PHP without having an endless loop on the C# program that taking the info from outsourced files?

For example, the command "/init" would initialize all the variables on the C# program.
Can I write a init.php file to send the "/init" command to the running C# windows application?
This will be in order to initialize all the variables on the **running** "Program.exe" by opening the URL "http://example.com/init.php".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of approache for [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

As I understand it, you want to do that without a loop. The thing is: You have to have a loop anyway to keep the console application alive. The programm is staretd. Executes all code. And then ends. You could block it via stuff like ReadKey(), but then it would not be able to process anything.

Unfortunately all approaches to IPC I know either require a loop. Or a GUI that already *has* a loop - the EventQueue. You will not get around some multitasking, and for that alone I always advise a GUI application.

It is also pretty unclear what data you actually want to send and what that application doe with that data. Depending on those requirements, it might be possible to just do this via commandline parameters.

However the biggest issue might be rights. Web Servers are notoriously vulnerable to hacking, being online 24/7/365. As a result, they are usually run under the most restrictive user rights imaginable. Read access to it's content and programm folder is the only thing you can asume. Reading anywhere else, writing or even Execution is not usually on the list of things it can do. And will raise some eyebrows from the admin too.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. The loop I was talking about is a loop to gather the info from third party data sources. For example a table in sql, called "Commands" and contains queue of commands that the c# program should execute. The loop has to be in the C# program, in which the commands data of "Commands" table is being read every a few seconds. The PHP script will insert the data to the table. Anyway this is a way I don't want and I want to do it otherway.

Comment: @tytopoo As you have poorly explained your way or why you want your way, I am left with a lot of red flags about it being a XY problem - nothing else.